# How to create a function wrapper in runtime?

Tags: objective-c, reflection, profiling, runtime

I want to run simple profiling on a function. When a function starts to run, the timer stars. when it finished, the time is printed to the log:

```
-(int) myFunc {
    [MyProfileService startTimer:@"myFuncTimer"];
    ... code ...
    [MyProfileService stopTimer:@"myFuncTimer"];
    return result;
}
```

This solution is messing with the production code. a more elegant soultion would be to statically register the timer in the class initialize method:

```
@implementation MyClass {

    +(void) initialize {
            [MyProfileService monitorFunction:@Selector(myFunc) inClass[Myclass class]];
    }
```

In order to achive this, I need to replace the implementation of myFunc with a new implementation:

```
-(void) runProfileFunc(....) {
    [MyProfileService startTimer:@"myFuncTimer"];
    id result = [MyClass performSelector:@selector(myFunc) withObject: ...];
    [MyProfileService stopTimer:@"myFuncTimer"];
    return result;
}
```

with objc/runtime I can switch functions in runtime. 
How can I replicate the original function signiture and pass the parameters to the original function inside the wrapper?

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel, have you looked into Instruments?

Comment: Are you doing this because a) you want to make it run faster, or b) you just want to know the measurement?

Comment: I want to collect the info from my beta testers but I don't want #if everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a utility that does just that:

https://github.com/tomersh/TheWrapper